# Ionic 4 returns different time value for Android & iOS

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic4

Here's my code:

```
var get_time = new Date(my_time.replace(' ','T')).getTime();
```

The values are different for Android & iOS.

I think there is some interference of timezones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the best way,
You can convert the date to utc and set the time by adding the timezone offset

Try the following

`get_time= new Date(new Date(get_time.replace(' ','T')+'Z').getTime()).setMinutes(new Date(new Date(get_time.replace(' ','T')+'Z').getTime()).getMinutes() + new Date(new Date(get_time.replace(' ','T')+'Z').getTime()).getTimezoneOffset());`

It will provide the correct time according to your local time.

Comment: GMT+5:30 time zone - 5:30 hours ahead Greenwich Mean Time

Comment: Yes. ios always adds timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

If you just put a 'T' instead of the space in the datetime string then it interprets correctly on iOS.

```
let iOSString = parsed_token.expires_at.replace(' ', 'T');

if(new Date(`${iOSString}`).getTime()/1000 > new Date().getTime()/1000) {
    // Handle the redirection for an invalid token.
}
```